# Confused about field modifers?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

For example if we had:

```
package a;

public class A {
    private int moo
    protected int cow
    int spot;
public A() {
}
}
```

and...

```
package p; 
Import p.A; 
public class C extends A {
    int what; 
public C (A a) {
 what = cow;
 what = spot; 
}
}
```

So why is what = spot is valid and what = spot isn't valid? (or at least according to my notes what = spot isn't valid.)

Comment: (Where is `zoo` declared?) See also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @Radiodef that is a imaginary term... that should actually be cow I'll fix that and my apologies.

Comment: `import` is written in lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `zoo` variable in your code. Anyway..

Since class `A` is in package `a`, class `C` in package `p`, `C` cannot access the package-private variable `spot`.
If you want `spot` to be accessible by extending classes, change its access modifier to `protected`.

Comment: Sorry the zoo thing was an oops moment... So if a variable doesn't get a modifier it is automatically private to items outside the package?

Comment: yes, that is correct. only those in the same package can access it directly. same goes for package-private methods.

Answer (score 0):

`spot`, having a default visibility, is NOT visible to any class other than within its own package, i.e. `package a`.

See more details here: [Visibility Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple access modifier issue and this is what default access modifier is for and separates it from others.
If a variable is given The default access then it is accessible only in the same package. Even if you extend the class in some other package.